# Random variable distribution depending on another random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> In the fire department, they agreed to practice as long as the
>   training session did not reach 22 seconds. They know from experience
>   that such a fast can only be with a probability of $0.2$.
>  ...
>   
>  Determine the distribution of the number of water tanks they
>   need in training. One tank is sufficient for five attempts.

Let $X$ be a random variable which says how many training sessions they had done until they didn't reached their goal. I think the distribution of $X$ is $P[X = k] = 0.2 \cdot (1-0.2)^{k-1}$.

Now I want to determine a distribution of the random variable $Y$ which says how many water tanks they need. It seems that: 
$P[Y=1]=P[1 \le X \le 5]$, 
$P[Y=2]=P[6 \le X \le 10]$, 
and so on. Is there any elegant way to determine distribution of $Y$?

Comment: Is it something like $P[Y=k] = 0.2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^5 0.8^{5(k-1)+(i-1)}$ ?